# Python read text file into dictionary, list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read a text file into a dictionary. 
The text file contains a person's name, networks, and friends' names.
The key for dictionary is person's name, and value is that person's networks
Here is the text file:

```
Pritchett, Mitchell\n
Law Association\n
Dunphy, Claire\n
Tucker, Cameron\n
Dunphy, Luke\n
\n\n
Tucker, Cameron\n
Clown School\n
Wizard of Oz Fan Club\n
Pritchett, Mitchell\n
Pritchett, Gloria\n
\n\n
Dunphy, Alex\n
Orchestra\n
Chess Club\n
Dunphy, Luke\n
```

Here is what I did

```
def person_to_networks(file):
```

I get an error for the line 'if "\n" and "," in lst[0]'. It says list index out of range.
Please help me. I can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

Comment: You are emptying your list in your first `if` block. Why?

Comment: I can't figure out your file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get that error because you are initializing your lst to be empty [ ], and then you check the first element which does not exist.

you say that you want to turn your file into a dictionary, I suggest this simpler code for that:

```
import re  # import regex library
# open the file and import your data
f = open('data', 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()
# initialize your data to be processed
dict = {}
data = data.replace('\\n', '') # remove \n characters
data = data.split('\n\n')      # split it into blocks
for block in data:
    block = block.split('\n')  # split each bock into lines
    nets = []
    for line in block:
        if ',' not in line and line != '': # find networks
            nets.append(line)
    block[0] = re.sub(r'(\w+),\s(\w+)', r'\2, \1', block[0])  # ADDED to switch first name and last name
    dict.update({block[0]: nets})   # update the result dictionary
print dict
```

and this will give you this result for your suggested file example:

```
{'Pritchett, Mitchell': ['Law Association'], 'Tucker, Cameron': ['Clown School', 'Wizard of Oz Fan Club'], 'Dunphy, Alex': ['Orchestra', 'Chess Club']}
```

if this is not what you want, please describe in more details what it is.

**Edit:** in order to switch the `first name` and `last name` you can add just that single line to make that switch before you update the dictionary. I added that line in the code above, it uses a regex (*don't forget to add "import re"  like in the beginning of my code*) :

```
'(\w+),\s(\w+)' # used to find the first name and last name and store them in \1 and \2 match groups.
'\2, \1'        # to replace the place of the match groups as required.
 OR '\2 \1'     # if you don't want the comma
```

and you can manipulate it however you like, e.g: you can remove the `,` or something like that.

and after the switching the output will become like:

```
{'Alex, Dunphy': ['Orchestra', 'Chess Club'], 'Cameron, Tucker': ['Clown School', 'Wizard of Oz Fan Club'], 'Mitchell, Pritchett': ['Law Association']}
```

**Edit:** another way to switch between the `first` and `last` names (*remove the "import re" and the previously added line and replace it with these three lines with the same indent*):

```
s = block[0].split(', ')
s.reverse()
block[0] = ', '.join(s)  # or use ' '.join(s) if you don't want the comma
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot. But I need to switch names as first name and last name. I wrote elif ',' in line: nets.append(block) but it doesn't switch name orders .

Comment: I added the switching, check it out ;)

Comment: how can I remove commas ? can I just add ','.remove() ?

Comment: to remove `,` from between `first` and `last` names just remove it from the regex : `'\2, \1'`, I added that to my answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! but is there any other ways to switch names ? other than re.sub()?

Comment: now I want update this result dictionary to new function include the data in open file, called def load_profiles(profiles_file, person_to_networks): and I wrote a code : profiles_file = open('data.txt','r') return person_to_networks(profiles_file) but this gives me an error profiles_file is not defined. could you help with this problem?

Comment: put both functions in the same python file, and remove the parameters from you `load_profiles( )` function. If more errors comes up,  I need to see the whole content and the indentation, so better open new question with clear code, your desired input, output, and what errors you get. Good luck!

Comment: I am really sorry to bother you, but could you please find what is wrong with my code for my other question? the link is    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753924/python-list-of-str-int-tuple-dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Because the first time through the loop, you're trying to access lst[0], when lst is still [].

Answer (score 0):

First line at least, lst is empty list (`[]`).
You should append some values to lst first.

---

Probably, you want to did following:

`if "\n" and "," in lst[0]:`
to
`if "\n" and "," in line[0]:`
,

`elif "," not in lst[1:]:`
to
`elif "," not in line[1:]:`

`new_person_friends` in the last line is not defined. You need fix that to right one.

---

When line is "\n", lst will clear after `networks`'s update.
And your data have "\n\n". That means 2 consecutive empty lines.
In the second "\n", lst is empty list because the first "\n" was processed.
You need fix your code to avoid that problem like this: `if line == '\n' and lst != []:`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I changed what you have suggested , but now I get an error in the line 'networks.update({lst[0]:lst[1:]})'. It says list index out of range..

Comment: @user3477470 After all errors have gone, you may think the created dictionary is not what you expected. If so, try to improve your algorithm yourself.