# python list of (str,int) tuple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to return list of `(str, int)` tuple, which is  the friend recommendations for the given person in a list of tuples where the first element of each tuple is a potential friend's name (in the same format as the dictionary keys) and the second element is that potential friend's score. Only potential friends with non-zero scores should be included in the list.

Here is an example of the format of the return value for this function:

```
[('Gloria Pritchett', 2),
 ('Manny Delgado', 1),
 ('Cameron Tucker', 1),
 ('Luke Dunphy', 3)]
```

For each person, all people in the social network who they are not currently friends with are potential friends. For a particular person, each potential friend is scored using the following point system:
For every mutual friend that the person and the potential friend have, add 1 point to the potential friend's score
For each network that the person and the potential friend both belong to, add 1 point to the potential friend's score
If the person has the same last name as the potential friend, add 1 point to the potential friend's score, but only if they have something else in common (mutual friend(s), mutual network(s) or both).
This is what I did:

and these are my two functions which works fine:
first function returns dictionary of key:names value:friends' names
second function returns dictionary of key:names value: networks

I get an error for `def make_recommendations`. I don't have any clue what is the problem .. Please help me.

Comment: Too many open parentheses on the previous line?

Comment: person_dict=person_to_friends(profiles_file) fives error..

Comment: I'm confused. You have a function named person_to_friends, but you're also passing that as an argument to make_recommendations. I have a feeling your error resides within the clash of those names.

Comment: Instead of _removing_ information, how about providing _more_? What is the _exact_ error message that you're receiving?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is doing what you think it's doing:

```
for key in person_to_friends or person_to_networks:
```

You can see what it's really doing by trying this:

```
for x in [1,2,3] or [4,5,6]:
    print x
```

This is effectively saying:

```
for value in (first list if it's not empty otherwise second list)
```

If you want to use the values in *both* lists, you should use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6]):
    print x
```

You make a similar error with:

```
if freind in person_to_friends[profiles_file] or person_to_networks[profiles_file]:
```

(**Note the typo in `freind`**. This is probably giving you your error. Also `profiles_file` isn't defined anywhere in this function, is it in the global scope?) You probably mean:

```
if friend in person_to_friends[profiles_file] or friend in person_to_networks[profiles_file]:
```

This is evaluated by Python as:

```
if (value in first sequence) OR (second sequence is not empty)
```

Also of note, in `person_to_friends`, you have:

```
name.update({lst[0]:lst[1:]})
```

While this is technically correct, it's a lot more overhead (in comprehension as well as in processing) than the traditional:

```
name[lst[0]] = lst[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that the problem is a bit complicated and contain many **intersections**, I suggest you simplify the solution and divide it to steps:

for example:

1. function to find the `score` of person's friends (return list of tuples):

   ```
   def friendsMu(person):
       result = []
       friends = person_to_friends[person]
       for key in person_to_friends:
           if key != person:
               friends2 = person_to_friends[key]
               intersect = list(set(friends) & set(friends2))
               p = len(intersect)
               if p != 0:
                   t = (key, p)
                   result.append(t)
       return result
   ```
2. function to find the `score` of person's networks (return list of tuples):

   ```
   def networkMu(person):
       result = []
       friends = person_to_networks[person]
       for key in person_to_networks:
           if key != person:
               friends2 = person_to_networks[key]
               intersect = list(set(friends) & set(friends2))
               p = len(intersect)
               if p != 0:
                   t = (key, p)
                   result.append(t)
       return result
   ```
3. function to calculate the results of the previous functions for `all persons` (return dictionary: `key` = `name`, `value` = `list of tuples`):

   ```
   def allf();
       ddict = {}
       for key in person_to_friends:
           d1 = friendsMu(key)
           if d1 != ():
               ddict[key] = d1
       return ddict

   def alln():
       ndict = {}
       for key in person_to_networks:
           d1 = networkMu(key)
           if d1 != ():
               ndict[key] = d1
       return ndict
   ```
4. function to `merge` the final result:

   ```
   from collections import Counter
   def mrg(ddict, ndict):
       merged = Counter(ddict)
       merged.update(ndict)
       return merged
   ```

Outputs would look like:

```
 print allf()
 allf() =  {'Jay Pritchett': [('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Cameron Tucker', 1), ('Gloria Pritchett', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1)], 'Claire Dunphy': [('Gloria Pritchett', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1)], 'Manny Delgado': [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Mitchell Pritchett', 1), ('Alex Dunphy', 1), ('Cameron Tucker', 1)], 'Mitchell Pritchett': [('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Phil Dunphy', 1), ('Alex Dunphy', 1)], 'Alex Dunphy': [('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Mitchell Pritchett', 1)], 'Cameron Tucker': [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1)], 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy': [], 'Phil Dunphy': [('Mitchell Pritchett', 1)], 'Dylan D-Money': [], 'Gloria Pritchett': [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Claire Dunphy', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1)], 'Luke Dunphy': [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Claire Dunphy', 1), ('Cameron Tucker', 1), ('Gloria Pritchett', 1)]}

 print alln()
 alln() =  {'Phil Dunphy': [], 'Claire Dunphy': [('Gloria Pritchett', 1)], 'Manny Delgado': [('Alex Dunphy', 1)], 'Mitchell Pritchett': [], 'Alex Dunphy': [('Manny Delgado', 1)], 'Cameron Tucker': [], 'Gloria Pritchett': [('Claire Dunphy', 1)]}

merged = mrg(allf(),alln())
for i in merged:                                                                 
    print i, merged[i]
merged = 
Jay Pritchett [('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Cameron Tucker', 1), ('Gloria Pritchett', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1)]
Claire Dunphy [('Gloria Pritchett', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1), ('Gloria Pritchett', 1)]
Manny Delgado [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Mitchell Pritchett', 1), ('Alex Dunphy', 1), ('Cameron Tucker', 1), ('Alex Dunphy', 1)]
Mitchell Pritchett [('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Phil Dunphy', 1), ('Alex Dunphy', 1)]
Alex Dunphy [('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Mitchell Pritchett', 1), ('Manny Delgado', 1)]
Cameron Tucker [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Manny Delgado', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1)]
Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy []
Phil Dunphy [('Mitchell Pritchett', 1)]
Dylan D-Money []
Gloria Pritchett [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Claire Dunphy', 1), ('Luke Dunphy', 1), ('Claire Dunphy', 1)]
Luke Dunphy [('Jay Pritchett', 1), ('Claire Dunphy', 1), ('Cameron Tucker', 1), ('Gloria Pritchett', 1)]
```

hope this helps, if not to give you exactly what you asked for, something to guide you.
Good luck.